# I can't insert a foreign key into my database

Tags: php, mysql

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Buchhandlung\gut.php on line 144 SQL Fehler in: INSERT
>   INTO tblbücher (Titel, ISBN, Herausgabedatum, fVerlageID) VALUES(?, ?,
>   ?, (Select VerlageID FROM tblverlage Where Name='Yen On'))

This is what my browser says as an error, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. I try to insert data into my table "tblbücher". The problem is, that I need to insert a foreign key but I cant display just "1, 2, 3, 4, 5,..." in the input form

```
    if ($titel!="" and $isbn!="" and $herausgabedatum!="" and $verlage!="" )
    {
    $sql=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tblbücher (Titel, ISBN, Herausgabedatum, fVerlageID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, (Select VerlageID FROM  tblverlage Where Name='$verlage'))");
    $sql->execute(array($titel, $isbn, $herausgabedatum, $verlage)) or die("SQL Fehler in: ".$sql->queryString." <br /> ".$sql->errorInfo()[2]);
    echo"<h1>Folgende Daten wurden der Tabelle Orte hinzugefügt:</h1></br> ";
    echo "<table>";
    echo

"<tr><th>Titel</th><th>Herausgabedatum</th><th>Name des Verlags</th><th>fVerlageID</th></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>$titel</td><td>$isbn</td><td>$herausgabedatum</td><td>$verlage</td></tr>";

}
```

[This is how my input form looks like. You see that I need to call the "Verlag" "Yen On" instead of the foreign key "1" because it looks much better, but it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whSTG.png)

Comment: IMHO the error message is crystal clear. Change `Name='$verlage'` to `Name= ?`

Comment: Oh, it worked. Thanks a lot. I tried so many things and you get it within 2 sec :D
Could you tell my what the "?" stands for? So that I can solve problems like these on my own in the future

Comment: Please read the doc and the examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: BTW: In HTML you can use `<option value="1">Yen On</option>`. Then you won't need a subquery for the FK.

Comment: Well but I put it this way 
echo "<option>$ds[Name]</option>";

Comment: Do you know what I could do there?

Comment: `echo "<option value='{$ds['VerlageID']}'>{$ds['Name']}</option>";`

Answer (score 1):

You're saying you need three variables in your PDO

```
VALUES(?, ?, ?, ...)
```

But you're specifying four

```
$sql->execute(array($titel, $isbn, $herausgabedatum, $verlage))
```